# Android: Accept all special characters in regex

Tags: java, android, regex, special-characters, validation

I'm validating the Edittext with regex by allowing particular characters
in that i need to allow all the special characters to enter in edit text.

for allowing alpha and numbers im using the code

```
edittext.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new PartialRegexInputFilter(
                    "[a-zA-z0-9]+") });
```

Like this i need to allow all special characters...

And also i try to give like this

```
edittext.setFilters(
new InputFilter[] 
    { new PartialRegexInputFilter(
        "[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&(){|}~:;<=>?@*+,./^_`-\'\" \t\r\n\f]+") 
    }
);` .
```

But this give error for single and double quote characters...

Comment: define "special character" ?

Comment: so what your question is ?

Comment: You know how to do it for `alphanumeric characters`. Now just negate that to get all other characters. If this does not works, then add a definition of Special Characters to your question.

Comment: it will change according to user define in front end... Sometime they will define only to type number with special characters..

Comment: And also i try to give like this [A-Za-z0-9!#$%&(){|}~:;<=>?@*+,./^_`-\'\" \t\r\n\f]. But this give error for single and double quote characters...

Comment: do you want to get only special characters or any combination with special character and alphanumeric characters

Answer (score 2):

Is there anything you want to disallow?  It sounds like you're trying to allow all alphanumeric character *and* allow all non-alphanumeric (i.e., special) characters.

The following regex will match all special characters:

```
[^A-Za-z0-9]
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding every special character, use `.*`.
This regex matches everything.

If you want to remove some characters from it, use `[^a!c]` alone, **without `.*`**, to match everything except `a`, `!` and `c`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem with your second pattern is the hyphen `(-)` in the middle of your character set.  Move it to the end:

```
[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&(){|}~:;<=>?@*+,./^_`\'\" \t\r\n\f-]+
```

Hyphens cannot be in the middle because they specify ranges of characters [a-z] specifies all lowercase letters between a through z.